Is there a way to save a Spacy Model after adding custom pipes to a Snowflake Stage?
I am working on Snowflake's UI Snowsight with a Python worksheet. This is my code:
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import col
import spacy
from spacy.language import Language
def main(session: snowpark.Session):
session.add_import("@my_python_packages_stage/classy_classification.zip")
import classy_classification
nlp=spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")
data={"Encryption required":['This','in'],"Encryption not required":['0','1']}
nlp.add_pipe("classy_classification",config={"data": data, "model": "spacy"})
i="This is in 1"
doc = nlp(i)
print(doc._.cats)
return "Classification Done"
This consists of a third party package - Classy Classification which is included as a Pipe in Spacy. I am trying to Save these updates(After adding Pipes) and save a final copy of the entire model with this pipe into a Snowflake Stage.
This would help me to make use of this model in another Python file. Saving this model into a zip file would be good too, to import it as a Stage Package in Snowflake. Please help me out with this approach or suggest some alternate approaches.
